# Having an issue getting JS script to work, can anyone see the problem here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im pretty sure the code Im using is correct but its not working and I cant figure out why. Its to make a button scroll back to the top of the page, so Im loading the jQuery library in the  tags, and then the script before the end of the  tag.

```
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
```

```
<div>
                <h1 id="backtotop" style="font-size:250%; text-align:center;">BACK TO TOP</h1>
            
         </div> 

        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    jQuery('#backtotop').click(function () {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1600);
        return false;
    });
});
  });
      </script>
```

Comment: it can be called with either...

Comment: Your issue is, one too many `});` - not surprising with your random indentation!! Therefore your javascript doesn't *parse* and you get a big error in the browser **developer** tools console which tells you that your code has an error

Comment: code looks good.

Comment: @YorkChen - except for the extra `});` ?

Comment: A quick google gave me [the answer on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `});` at in your code

See snippet

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // scroll body to 0px on click
  jQuery('#backtotop').click(function() {
    jQuery('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1600);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div style="height:1000px;background:#eee"></div>
<div>
  <h1 id="backtotop" style="font-size:250%; text-align:center;">BACK TO TOP</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: This works and builds upon the code of the OP, however, you should always try to use semantically correct HTML-tags due to accessibility concerns. Here, `<h1>` has a click-event, but every keyboard-user won't be able to click it, since it is has both no tabindex and has no KeyEvent-listener attached to it. You should have instead used a `<button>`, since that makes the browser handle all the above tasks implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As the guy who commented says, you can use jquery using `$`.
And you also had too many close brackets.

This here works:
$(document).ready(function(e){

// scroll body to 0px on click
$('#backtotop').click(function () {

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 1600);
return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle to check: `https://jsfiddle.net/sparkmig/43f6e02L/3/`